# how to change the content of the row in jqgrid depending on the value of the previous row selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

i am using jqgrid to show the contents on page, but i want to change the contents of the list of the current row depending on the value i have selected in previous row. Like we do in onchange event in javascript by sending ajax request to the server.

Comment: Any sample code? How do you select a value in the previous row, from a select menu?

Comment: It's really difficult to understand what you mean. Do you use some editing mode and you mean selection of an option from the `<select>` or you mean just simple selection (highlighting) of the row and you want to do some additional actions inside of your `onSelectRow` handler?

Answer (score 0):

So supposing your data is selected from a drop-down in one of the rows, it should make an AJAX call and populate the next row accordingly. See if the following code provides any help to you.

```
$('#select-id').on("change", function(){
  //make an AJAX call, retrieve data in 'data' variable
  var trdata = '<td>'+data.element1+'</td>'+'<td>'+data.element2+'</td>';
  $(this).closest('tr').next().html(trdata);
});
```